# How to optimize SQL Query when you have more than 100 where Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Currently I have a view called `vStoreProduct` which has following columns

```
DOEntry   |  StoreID  | UpcCode | Value
```

Now my users filter `StoreID` and `UpcCode` usually I have around more than 500 Stores and more than 700 UpcCode.

In my frontend or user interface, user can select anything ie

- All Store & All Product
- Some Store or some product

Now the outcome `SQL` Query is something like this

```
select count(*) from vStoreProduct where StoreID in ( ..................) and 
UpcCode      in (.....................)
```

Currently even a count is taking more than 3 mins for a view of 500,000 records.

Is this the best approach or would you recommend something else.

Thanks

Comment: best approach would be have indexes on view/table  on storeid and upccode coumn

view with schemaninding https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms191432.aspx

Comment: You have a lot of data on the query itself. Moving it so a temporary object, and maybe even considering indexes for it would improve performance for the final aggregated query.

Comment: Probably you are having table/Index scans that is causing main issue

or might be you are having cardinality issue.

, have multicolumn index on the View (if with view is with schemaninding) your query will use index 
for fast retrieving the data and multicolumn index will improve
 cardinality estimation as well , and that wlll result better estimation for  rows and might provide sufficient memory.
NOTE AS I CANT SEE EXECUTION PLAN SO THIS IS JUST A GUESS

Answer (score 0):

What is the code in vStoreProduct? Is it just a simple select for one (or more) base tables, or does it contain more logic that is the root cause for the slowness? If it's complex, can you use an indexed view instead?

If the view is simple, are the fields you use indexed? Have you looked at statistics io output or checked heavy operations from execution plan (table / index scans, sorts and key lookups for large number of rows, spools).

If the view contains 500 000 rows, how many of these are you fetching when it takes 3 minutes? How many rows are in the base tables?